# My AppStore Updater wants to install the latest RAW update over and over again

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update, aperture

Somehow my OS X AppStore is caught in a loop. It wants to install the RAW updates for Aperture and iPhoto over and over again. What should I do?

[image: AppStore installs RAW update over and over again]

Comment: Is ignoring it for 24 hours to let the avalanche of iOS 8 download clear the queue a viable next step for you?

Comment: I guess so. Will try again tomorrow and report back.

Comment: It might not be related, but I'd hate to have you do a lot of troubleshooting if it's just a capacity issue on the CDN Apple uses to stage and report updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed seems to have been a load problem. After one night, the update and the notification for the update have gone. Seems the iOS8 downloads have pretty much irritated the AppStore.